# OpenLayers. New features doesn't select (multilayer)

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/runixer/6FDQ3/12/

To reproduce the problem: draw some features with the help of bottom toolbar, and try to highlight them. Only features on the last (third) layer will highlight. I feel that the bug is in my code, but I can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like only one SelectFeature Control can be active:
http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2012-June/025307.html

Solution is to use one SelectFeature for all vector Layers:
http://jsfiddle.net/6FDQ3/13/